# Short story: alien intelligence take-over in Antarctic base

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I'd like to track down an English-language short story I read sometime between 1990 and 2010 approx, and which I'm fairly sure was in a UK-edition anthology.

It's about an alien intelligence (monster?) which had taken-over/mind-controlled/inhabited the mind and/or body of a female industrial worker/scientist in an underground(?) facility/lab/drilling site in Antarctica, or somewhere similarly cold and icy, while her male partner/co-worker tries to help. There's a multi-level circular shaft with some sort of machine at the top, where most of the story takes place. The time setting is now, or the not-too distant future.

Comment: Are you thinking of the short story, *"Who Goes There?"*, or the movie, *The Thing*?

Comment: This rings a distant bell. Is there any more information you can give? How did it end?

Comment: Sorry, not really, except that the male and female were talking on a gallery of the shaft, near the end of the story, still under the 'influence' of the alien. Any more than that would just be wishful thinking...

Comment: No, definitely not John W Campbell's story, but your suggestion prompts me to add the probable time setting to my question, which may help, thanks.